# simple GUI application but can not find add symbol

Tags: file, user-interface

We have just recently started learning about GUI in my computer science class. We were told to

Design a GUI application as shown below and perform the following tasks:
1.  The text field is for data file name, the length of file name should be between 5 and 10, and file extension must be .txt, otherwise, prompt user to provide a valid file name.
2.  Load the content of the data file and display on the textarea.

This is what my code says so far

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileLoader implements ActionListener {


private final LayoutManager layout;
private JButton loadButton;
private JTextField filename;
private JTextArea display;

public FileLoader() 
{

 layout = new FlowLayout();
  setLayout(layout);
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

   loadButton = new JButton("Load File");
   filename = new JTextField(10);
   buttonPanel.add(filename );
   buttonPanel.add(loadButton);
   display = new JTextArea(25, 50);

   add(new JLabel("File Name: "));
    add(filename);
  add(new JScrollPane(display));
  add(loadButton);

   loadButton.addActionListener(this);


 }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
try{

   String file = filename.getText();
   int filesize = file.length();

if (filesize>= 5 && filesize<= 10){
  Scanner input = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream(file));
  String DisTXT = " ";
  while (input.hasNextLine()){
   DisTXT = DisTXT  + input.nextLine();
  if (input.hasNextLine()){
      DisTXT = DisTXT  + "\n";
}
}
display.setText(DisTXT);
input.close();
 }


else
{
if (filesize< 5){
 display.setText("File NAME ERROR: NAME IS TOO SHORT");
} 
else {
display.setText("File NAME ERROR: NAME IS TOO LONG");
}

 }
}
catch (NullPointerException e) { 
display.setText("File not found");
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   new FileLoader();

}
}
```

but for some reason, it can not find the add method, i always thought it was automatically picked up by the imports, is this not the case? how can one ix this?
I'm sorry if this a rather frivolous question, this part of computer science is completly new to me.

and also i used

```
layout = new FlowLayout();
setLayout(layout);
```

in our last lab, but instead it was grid layout. it worked last time but wont this time, can someone please explain why? Thank you in advance

Comment: From your explanation it seems to me that your previous application's Main class was extending JFrame. It allow you to add various components and such without calling a field. This time, you're trying to call the add() function on a class that doesn't have one, not to mention, the implemented interface only acts as a blueprint. In this application, youre not extending JFrame, but instead made a JFrame field. If I understand your app correctly, just add "frame." in front of your add() and setLayout().

Answer (score 0):

What's happening in your code is just a matter of inheritance. If you extends a class with JFrame, you borrow all its methods into the new subclass. Example 1 below:

```
public class GUIappExtend extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new GUIappExtend();
    }

    public GUIappExtend() 
    {
        setSize(200, 100);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Another option to make a JFrame field in your main class to which you manage your display. Example 2 below:

```
public class GUIappNoExtend
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       new GUIappNoExtend();
    }
    public GUIappNoExtend() 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(200, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

As you can see, in example 1, I can just call the setSize() function without specifying from what field I'm calling. This is because I have inherited these "hidden" functions into the subclass. In example 2 I can't just call the function setSize(), because the class doesn't own a function with that name. I can instead make a field from a JFrame, and call the setSize() function there.

All this is also true for the add() and setLayout() function in your application. I hope this makes the issue clear to you.

**TL;DR** - the add() and setLayout() function belongs to the JFrame class in this case. You can only call these functions if the source class owns a function by that name.

Comment: It compiles now! but when i go to run the program nothing opens up, no GUI

Comment: That's correct. Call .setVisible(true) on the frame to show it.